# How to keep the program from crashing from invalid input

Tags: c#

I created a player class and made a array from that class for my menu driven player system I am trying to validate user input. I made a GetChar and a GetInt method to check that the user has entred a char and Int but I am not sure on how to validate that the user has entred a postive number and not a negative number for the player number, goals and assists.

Any help would be appreciated

```
//Creates a player in the tables if the array is not already full and the name is not a duplicate
    static void ProcessCreate(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
        Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)

    {
        string message;
        //Int32 player = 0;
        if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
        {
           message =("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's number");
           number = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
       //(Console.ReadLine());
            if (GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount) == -1)
            {
                message =("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's First Name");
                firstName = IOConsole.Getstring(message);
                  //Console.ReadLine();
                message = ("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's Last  Name");
                lastName = IOConsole.Getstring(message);
                 //Console.ReadLine();
                message =("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's goals");
                goals = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
               //Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             message =("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's assists");
             assists = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
                 //Console.ReadLine();
                InsertPlayer(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}\n", "Number", "First Name", "Last Name", "Goals", " Assists", "Points");
                for (Int32 player = 0; player < playerCount; player++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}",
              players[player].Number, players[player].FirstName, players[player].LastName,
              players[player].Goals, players[player].Assists, players[player].Points());


                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a library to access console input?

Comment: Probably you should show the code for IOConsole.GetInt32 where the problem exists.

Comment: If you do not know how to check if a number is negative, then why are you attempting to do the above code?

Answer (score 2):

Start with the right data type - if you use a type that **cannot** be negative, you are already ahead.

So - you can use `byte`, `ushort`, `uint` or `ulong`, depending on your model (say a max of 8 players - use a `byte`).

It is not clear *how* your users are entering these values - if a programmer using your library, the above goes a long way towards ensuring things go according to your wishes.

If these are bits of text entered by users (on a UI or command line, for instance), you will need to parse the values - the .NET framework provides `Parse` and `TryParse` on all integral types (such as the ones above). These will allow you to check that the values input by users are valid, according to your validation rules.

If you have a more complex UI, selecting the correct type of UI element can ensure these kinds of problem never come up (radio buttons for number of players, where the values are completely in your control, for example - not saying this is great UI, just that you have the option and the control).

Checking these and returning an error to the user is quite normal.

---

If you are "stuck" with a type that is signed (that is, can have negative values), just check the value against 0:

```
'if (val <= 0)` // not positive
```

---

As a note - if you can't validate input, crashing on invalid input is probably a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simply do while loop. Get the user input and then check to see if the value is less than 0. If it's less than 0 renter the value.

```
do
{
    // get user input
} while(message < 0);
```